# css odd and even selector not working

Tags: css, sass

I'm creating a rating control made of half stars and I want to be able to select odd and even labels inside the .rating control. The selector shoudl look like this but it's not working here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/ZyGRmM) check my html out while your there

```
.rating {
    label:nth-child(odd)::before {} // not working
}
.rating {
    label:nth-child(even)::before {} // not working
}
```

Full CSS:

```
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;    
}

body {
  background: #272727;  
}

.rating { 
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  

label {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;    
  color: #afa302;
}

label.half_l::before {
  content: '\f006';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 11px;
  overflow: hidden;    
}  

label.half_r {

  width: 12px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
label.half_r::before {
  content: '\f006';
  display: inline-block;
  left: -11px;
  position: relative;    
}  

label {
  float: right;
}  

label:hover {
  color: #fff239;    
}

> input {
  display: none;
}

label.half_l:hover:before,
label.half_l:hover ~ label.half_l:before {
  content: '\f089';
  color: #fff239;
}

label.half_l:hover ~ label.half_r::before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #fff239;
}

label.half_r:hover:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #fff239;
}

label.half_r:hover ~ label.half_r::before,
label.half_r:hover ~ label.half_l:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #fff239;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ label.half_l:before,
input[type=radio]:checked ~ label.half_r:before{
  content: '\f005';
}
```

}

Comment: Please include enough code to replicate the problem **in the question itself**. Better still use Stack Snippets (the `<>` button) to  provide a [MCVE]

Comment: If you're using a CSS preprocessor you should mention that as your original CSS is not even remotely valid.

Comment: @JonP An update of the questions tags fixes that...which I just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If to use the `nth-child` selector you need to bypass the `input`'s since it count all children no matter their type

The `nth-child(4n+4)` start from the 4:th element (your second label) and then counts to every 4:th and apply the rule, which in your case will be every *even* label

The `nth-child(4n+2)` start from the 2:nd element (your first label) and then counts to every 4:th and apply the rule, which in your case will be every *odd* label.

*Note, one can also use `nth-child(4n)` instead of `nth-child(4n+4)`, which will start from the 0:th element (which does not exists) and then counts to every 4:th.*

```
.rating {
    label:nth-child(4n+4)::before {
      background: yellow;
  }
}
.rating {
    label:nth-child(4n+2)::before {
      background: blue;
  }
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MowPjO)

Answer (score 3):

Use `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`

```
label:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:red; 
}
```

`nth-child` looks for all children, regardless their type, where `nth-of-type` looks for a certain type

Comment: I made an edit (hope you don't mind :), and an upvote